# Overriding model class causes constructor err in magento 2

Tags: overrides, model, magento2.2, plugin

I' tired to override `\magento\module-configurable-product\Model\ConfigurableAttributeData.php` with plugin.

For this in my di.xml i have this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ConfigurableAttributeData">
        <plugin name="plugin-name" type="Vendor\Namespace\Model\ConfigurableAttributeData" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>

</config>
```

and in my ConfigurableAttributeData.php i have this code:

```
<?php
namespace namespace\module\Model;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable\Attribute;

class ConfigurableAttributeData
{

    /**
     * get all values of size attributes
     * @return array
     *
     */
    public function allOptions(){
      ......
    }

    /**
     * get product stockbase qty
     * @return array
     */

    public function getStockbaseQty($ean){

     ......

    }

    /**
     * @param Attribute $attribute
     * @param array $config
     * @return array
     */
    protected function aftergetAttributeOptionsData($attribute, $config)
    {   //load object managerand stock manager to get product qty
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $StockState = $objectManager->get('\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface');

        if($attribute->getId() == '1044') {
            $all_attributes = $this->allOptions();
            $attributeOptionsData = [];
            foreach ($all_attributes as $attributeOption) {
                //create new array with the same values as the original array
                $attributeOption['value_index'] = $attributeOption['option_id'];
                $attributeOption['label'] = $attributeOption['store_default_value'];
                $attributeOption['product_super_attribute_id'] = $attribute->getAttributeId();
                $attributeOption['default_label'] = $attributeOption['default_value'];
                $attributeOption['store_labe'] = $attributeOption['store_default_value'];
                $attributeOption['use_default_value'] = 1;
                $optionId = $attributeOption['value_index'];

                if (isset($config[$attribute->getAttributeId()][$optionId])) {
                    $product_details =  $config[$attribute->getAttributeId()][$optionId];
                    $product_id= $product_details[0];
                    $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);
                    $stock = $StockState->getStockQty($product->getId(), $product->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
                    //get product ean
                    if($product->getData('barcode')){
                        $Stock_value = $this->getStockbaseQty($product->getData('barcode'));
                        $Stock_value_int =  intval($Stock_value[0]['amount']);
                        $stockBaseQty =  $Stock_value_int;
                    }else{
                        $stockBaseQty = 0;
                    }
                    if($stock == 0 && $stockBaseQty ==0){
                        $attributeOption['value_index'] = $attributeOption['option_id'];
                        $attributeOptionsData[] = [
                            'id' => $optionId,
                            'label' => $attributeOption['label'],
                            'products' => isset($config[$attribute->getAttributeId()][$optionId])
                                ? $config[$attribute->getAttributeId()][$optionId]
                                : [],
                            'outofstock'=>1,
                        ];
                    }else{
                        $attributeOption['value_index'] = $attributeOption['option_id'];
                        $attributeOptionsData[] = [
                            'id' => $optionId,
                            'label' => $attributeOption['label'],
                            'products' => isset($config[$attribute->getAttributeId()][$optionId])
                                ? $config[$attribute->getAttributeId()][$optionId]
                                : [],
                        ];
                    }}
            }
            return $attributeOptionsData;
        }else{
            $attributeOptionsData = [];
            foreach ($attribute->getOptions() as $attributeOption) {
                $optionId = $attributeOption['value_index'];
                $attributeOptionsData[] = [
                    'id' => $optionId,
                    'label' => $attributeOption['label'],
                    'products' => isset($config[$attribute->getAttributeId()][$optionId])
                        ? $config[$attribute->getAttributeId()][$optionId]
                        : [],
                ];
            }
            return $attributeOptionsData;

        }
    }

}
```

When i refresh the page i receive this err:

```
2017/12/11 19:45:37 [error] 25376#25376: *5139 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 8 passed to Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable\Interceptor::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ConfigurableAttributeData, instance of namespace\Module\Model\ConfigurableAttributeData given, called in /data/web/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 111 and defined in /data/web/public/generated/code/Magento/ConfigurableProduct/Block/Product/View/Type/Configurable/Interceptor.php:11
```

.....

I deleted var/generation folder multiple times, i run php bin/magento setup:di:compile, i deleted cache.. I tried to override with preferences:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ConfigurableAttributeData" type="namespace\module\Model\ConfigurableAttributeData" />
</config>
```

but everythime i receive the same err.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the class `\Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ConfigurableAttributeData` I can see that [`getAttributeOptionsData()`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/ConfigurableProduct/Model/ConfigurableAttributeData.php#L56) is `protected` and you can not use `plugin` in `Non-public methods`. Also, you can not use plugin on below types,

- Objects that are instantiated before `Magento\Framework\Interception` is bootstrapped
- Final methods
- Final classes
- Any class that contains at least one final public method
- Non-public methods
- Static methods
- `__construct`
- `Virtual` types

So if its your custom requirement then override this class by using the `preference` rather then `plugin`.

---

**EDIT**

If you are using `preference` then please remove the code plugin which you have define in `di.xml` and also there is no need to write `after`in original method

`protected function getAttributeOptionsData($attribute, $config)`

and you need to extend the parent class `Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ConfigurableAttributeData`.

Also, from the conversion I think you are mixing the concept of `plugin` and `preference` but in real both things are different It would be hard to write all the things in one answer but I would suggest you to read on [Inchoo](http://inchoo.net/magento-2/overriding-classes-magento-2/) blog about this

Comment: thank you for the response. as you see, i wrote in the question that i tried to override using preferaces too, and i receive the same err

Comment: In question I can not find the code of `preference ` that's why i wrote this answer. If you tried then please update your question with code no one have misunderstanding. @AlinLupoiu

Comment: i have updated my question with preferance code.

Comment: thanks, please remove the `plugin` code from your `di.xml` and execute `setup:di:compile` command and check @AlinLupoiu

Comment: i did this before and no result. i receive the same thing:(

Comment: see my edit .. :) @AlinLupoiu

Comment: working fine. thank you very much. have a nice day!